# PyQt4 stretch LineEdit to window width

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I would like to stretch the QLineEdit widget to window width.
Here is the code with widget to be stretched marked <---HERE

```
import sys
from PyQt4.Qt import *

# Create the QApplication object
qt_app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class HWApp(QWidget):
    ''' Basic Qt app'''
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize the object as a QLabel
        QWidget.__init__(self) #, "Hello, world!")

        # Set the size, alignment, and title
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(800, 600))

        self.setWindowTitle('Hello, world!')
        self.tbox = QLineEdit("simple text",self)#<---HERE
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

    def run(self):
        ''' Show the app window and start the main event loop '''
        self.show()
        qt_app.exec_()

# Create an instance of the app and run it
HWApp().run()
```

What has to be added to stretch it to whole window width and keep it scalable with window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a layout:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.Qt import *

# Create the QApplication object
qt_app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class HWApp(QWidget):
    ''' Basic Qt app'''
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize the object as a QLabel
        QWidget.__init__(self) #, "Hello, world!")

        # Set the size, alignment, and title
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(800, 600))

        self.setWindowTitle('Hello, world!')
        self.tbox = QLineEdit("simple text", alignment=Qt.AlignCenter) # <---HERE
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.tbox)
        lay.addStretch()

    def run(self):
        ''' Show the app window and start the main event loop '''
        self.show()
        qt_app.exec_()

# Create an instance of the app and run it
HWApp().run()
```

[image]

If you want to eliminate the space on the sides, it is only necessary to set those margins to zero (Although I prefer preferring it with margins since it is more aesthetic):

```
lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> void QWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
>
> This event handler can be reimplemented in a subclass to receive widget resize events which are passed in the event parameter. When resizeEvent() is called, the widget already has its new geometry.

```
# ...
    self.tbox = QLineEdit("simple text", self)            # <---HERE
    self.tbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)                # +++

def resizeEvent(self, event):                             # +++
    self.tbox.resize(self.width(), 30)
# ...
```

[image]